# Where does xfce4 hold its application references?

Tags: arch-linux, xfce

I just started up an application that created an shortcut icon in the applications menu of xfce4. However, I moved the entire application to /opt (This is a good place to put non native package managed applications right?) and so the shortcut now doesn't find the bin, because well its not there anymore. I can make a symlink to patch this, but that's ugly.

Where does xfce4 keep its shortcuts text for its applications? (just can't find it, tried looking in ~/.config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after digging for some time, I did actually find it.

For me, it was located at `~/.local/share/applications` and there was the application's `.desktop` file (basically a config file).

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the contents of the "Applications" menu, I don't know off hand exactly where it is stored but it can be configured through the `alacarte` application (at least, that's the case in Debian's Xfce 4.8).

It should be listed as Applications -> Settings -> Main Menu; otherwise, just run it like some other application through the Run dialog or through a terminal.

Panel launchers simply need a right-click, `Properties` and `Edit the currently selected item` (bottom button to the right) to access the invocation command.

As for your choice of /opt, it seems [the FHS prefers /usr/local](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) but [/opt should be acceptable as well](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES).

Comment: Hmm, so I don't have a the `alacarte` application and trying to do a right click on the icon has the effect of a left click, aka its trying to start it up anyway. Not sure what to do besides the symlink now.

Comment: Debian provides alacarte through [a separate package](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/alacarte); maybe Arch does the same and you simply need to install it? Note the difference between the panel launchers and the application menu items; the menu doesn't respond specifically to right-clicks. Surely Arch would provide a means to edit the menu.

Comment: Just looked up alacarte, pacman (arch package manager) says that alacarte is for gnome =/

Comment: Check the page I linked to; Debian says *It works with the freedesktop.org menu specification and **should work with any desktop environment that uses the spec.***

Comment: Okay, just installed it. New problem, alacarte doesn't see the installed application's icon. Giving up now, going with the symlink.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work out for you. Hopefully this will at least help someone else.

Comment: A lighter alternative to alacarte is [menulibre](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/menulibre/).